# trigger function by click on anchor tag and get all children of it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to make a chat just like instagram, for the threads to appear I have a series of divs wrapped around anchor tags.

```
<ul id="Threadbox">
            
<li>
     <a class="thread" href="javascript:get_messages(atag)">//"atag" refers to the current anchor tag element
          <div>
               <a href="/inbox/dummy">dummy</a>
               <p>Doing great man</p>
         </div>
     </a>
</li>
<li>
     <a class="thread" href="javascript:get_messages(atag)"> //"atag" refers to the current anchor tag element
           <div>
               <a href="/inbox/sufyan">sufyan</a>
               <p>Hello</p>
          </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

This is all generated with javascript, what I want to do is trigger a function whenever this main anchor tag is clicked which will retrieve all the children of the anchor tag but when I try to do it it only gives me the anchor tag, not its children nodes
Following is the used js script

```
var threads={{ Threads|safe }}
    var messages={{ Messages|safe }}
    const l=threads.length
    const threadholder=document.querySelector("#Threadbox")
    for(i=0;i<=l;i++){
        var thread=document.createElement("li")
        var main=document.createElement("a")
        
        var div=document.createElement("div")
        var a=document.createElement("a")
        main.className="thread"
        var data=JSON.parse(threads[i])
        var Message=JSON.parse(messages[i])
        var username =data.second.username
        if (username=="{{ user.username }}"){
            username=data.first.username
        }
   var p=document.createElement("p")
        
   p.innerText=Message.message
   a.href= `/inbox/${username}`
   a.innerText=username
   div.appendChild(a)
   div.appendChild(p)
   main.appendChild(div)
   thread.appendChild(main)
   threadholder.appendChild(thread)
   main.href="javascript:"+"get_messages(main)"

};
function get_messages(a){
   console.log(a.children)
}
```

It feels like I am doing things the wrong way, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: where is `get_messages()..` function and where are children node ?

Comment: apologies forgot to add get_messages(), and the children nodes are that main variables' children is that div element and div has two children of another anchor tag and a p tag. as defined with appendchild method.

Comment: [Use a validator!](https://validator.nu/). Nested `<a>` elements are forbidden.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? @Quentin I do not get how to implement it.